# How does the Canvas work with MVC Frameworks?

Tags: angularjs, html5-canvas, javascript-framework, kineticjs

I've been looking into AngularJS and its MVC solution. Typically a MVC framework uses the HTML structure itself to bind to a backend data model. In AngularJS's case this is done with Directives, which work dandy for straight HTML.

For my scenario I have a data model that will be transmuted into a visual representation on an immediate mode Canvas. Then the visual items rendered will also need to be interacted with in order to edit the values in the backend data model.

What is the best way to achieve two way binding like this between items and the item values in a data model within a MVC framework?

Comment: 5 months on, what did you decide to use, how did it go? I'm facing the same decision and would to hear how you went.

Answer (score 3):

Angulars strength is that it deals with the DOM for you without you having to worry about it. If you were to use SVG instead, you could let Angular deal with updating the view since SVG is DOM but if you need to use a canvas instead, Angular can't handle the drawing for you.

You can still benefit from using Angular by using watches and redrawing your canvas when data changes, but you need to deal with the drawing yourself.

Comment: The canvas is needed for speed on mobile platforms plus the nature of my tools. Maybe a API like Fabric or Kinetic can make mapping a model to a canvas and two way binding easier? Not sure since I have not found examples of this. I still want to use DOM based DIVs, SVG and D3 widgets floating on top of the canvas. For example simple DIV based icons as HUD based tools overtop the canvas, these could still have AngularJS directives. Have not seen examples of this either but I'm sure it can be done.